# How to lower space between label and field for Vuetify input controls?

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

Given a customized Vuetify textfield as an example

([Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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))

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-text-field
        label="label goes here"
        variant="plain"
        density="compact"
        hide-details="auto"
        color="primary"
        class="my-1"
        model-value="some text goes here"
      />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</template>

<style scoped>
  :deep(.v-input),
  :deep(.v-field),
  :deep(.v-label--clickable) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  :deep(.v-label.v-field-label) {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

The vertical space between the label and the content is too much

[image]

What is the best way to lower the space? I tried to add

```
  .v-input {
    height: 4px;
    min-height: 4px;
    max-height: 4px;
  }

  .v-field {
    height: 4px;
    min-height: 4px;
    max-height: 4px;
  }

  .v-text-field {
    height: 4px;
    min-height: 4px;
    max-height: 4px;
  }
```

to see what happens but nothing changed.

Comment: You need to set min-height whatever you want. @baitendbidz

Comment: would you mind providing an example? That didn't work for me

Comment: v-field__input in this class you need to set min-height.

Comment: that worked :) but why should I set a min-height... ? It doesn't make a difference if I set it to 2px or 10px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is shifted on the Y-axis. When encountering such an issue, always use browser developer tools to identify the element whose position you don't understand, to find out "why it is there." Look for irrelevant settings and modifications that, when adjusted, will yield the desired result.

Factors influencing element position:

- generally `position`, with `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` (position changes relative to another element)
- `margin`, `padding`, `border` (developer tools indicate these)
- less frequently, transformations (`translateX()`, `translateY()`, `translateZ()`)

#### Solution (label transform too high)

```css
.v-field--variant-plain .v-label.v-field-label--floating {
  transform: translate(0px);
}
```

[Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't work for me ( in the playground )

Comment: I think this is some default class where formatting is specified with deep references. If you add `!important` at the end, CSS will ignore the overrides from deeper references, and this will be the valid one... If you don't want to use `!important`, you just need to derive the request through multiple parent classes. The solution is validated and tested.

Comment: Clearly, it's the -16px that causes the difference on the Y-axis... so there is exactly a 16px "spacing" between the two elements. What you perceive as spacing is actually the distance between the two elements achieved through some positioning by the package creator.

Comment: It worked for me... I added playground to my answer.

Comment: ah sorry, you wrapped `deep` around. This worked :)